# cp command using two variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use cp command using two variable but doesn't work

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH="/home/smvm/Dropbox/ssd-tech/SoftSwitch"


SRCPATH=${PATH}/lib/SIPLib/*.a
DESTPATH=${PATH}/include

cp "$SRCPATH" "$DESTPATH"
```

Following Error Occurs

```
copyPaste.sh: 9: copyPaste.sh: cp: not found
```

Comment: See: [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/3776858)

Comment: `PATH` is a poor choice of variable name.  Call it `path` (or `top`, or something).

Answer (score 6):

`PATH` is a special variable used to locate executables. Change `PATH` in your script with another variable (preferably a lower-case one) and your problem will be solved:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir="/home/smvm/Dropbox/ssd-tech/SoftSwitch"


srcfiles=${dir}/lib/SIPLib/*.a
destdir=${dir}/include

cp $srcfiles "$destdir"
```

As a general advice - don't use ALL UPPERCASE VARIABLES in your bash scripts, in order to avoid potential conflicts with reserved environment variables.

Comment: Correct, `$srcfiles` must be unquoted for the glob expansion to work. I updated the answer.

Comment: Please edit "$destdir" as $destdir

Comment: @S.M.AMRAN No, `$destdir` must remain quoted, so that it is not expanded and always remains as a single argument

Comment: Note that putting a glob in a variable isn't good practice. Since it requires the parameter remain unquoted, `srcfiles` couldn't contain a path containing whitespace, e.g., `srcfiles="/home/me/My Libraries/SIPLib/*.a"`. Use the pattern to populate an array instead. `srcfiles=( "$dir"/lib/SIPLib/*.a )`, then `cp "${srcfiles[@]}" "$destdir"`.